# Linear Regression without labels

Tags: linear-regression

Recently, I have encountered with a problem of linear regression. Let me explain the objective first:

I have a total of N number of samples for four features namely: f1, f2, f3, f4

I wish to find the weighted sum of these features (Q)

where: w1×f1 + w2×f2 + w3×f3 + w4xf4 = Q................(1)

Now my objective is to find the weights w1, w2, w3, and w4.

Here the important thing to notice is apart from weights, Q is also unknown.

What I have done is

w1×f1 + w2×f2 + w3×f3 + w4xf4 - Q = 0 ................(2)

w1×f1 + w2×f2 + w3×f3 + w4xf4 + Qx(-1) = 0................(3)

Now from equation (3), I have assumed  "-1" as my fifth feature f5 (say) and Q as the weight of f5.

Afterward, I have regressed this equation for the value zero "0" for all the samples. After some epochs, it has converged with error 0.005.

Now, my doubt is: I have no explanation about whether I am doing right or this is an incorrect approach. Anyone, please tell me the explanation about this approach. Thanks in advance.